Why doesn't spring-cloud-sleuth work with spring-boot 2.7 and webflux properly?
We have a spring-boot 2.7.18 application, where we use webflux. For tracking the process flow we are using spring-cloud-sleuth. There is no problem when an endpoint is being called, our process is traced well.
But we have some polling mechanism, where we periodically polling messages from an API. Before spring-boot 2.7, these processes got the traceId and spanId from sleuth, but after upgrading to 2.7 this stopped working.
We have this processing similar to this.
 public void start() {
        Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .flatMap(tick -> apiCall())
            .flatMap(message -> processing())
                .subscribe();
}

With this approach we don't have traceId and the spanId in the logs after spring-boot 2.7.
After some investigation I modified the implementation, because sleuth needs to be triggered and @Scheduled is a good way to do that.
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 500)
public void process() {
    if (sink != null) {
        sink.next(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
public void start() { // start called from main first
        Flux.create(emitter -> sink = emitter)
            .flatMap(tick -> apiCall())
            .flatMap(message -> processing())
                .subscribe();
}

In this way the traceId and spanId are generated properly, but when I see the logs coming from the flux chain, I can see duplicates, which is not right. I can imagine that maybe the problem could relate to not right context propagation.
Maybe updating to spring boot 3+ could solve our issue, but for the time being we are sticked to it.
Can you explain why this behaviour could happen and how should I solve this?
Many thanks!
